# How to see load test Raw data(like we can export raw data in to csv file to check transaction responses, users etc) using loadrunner in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, raw-data

How to see load test Raw data(like we can export raw data in to csv file to check transaction responses, users etc) using loadrunner  in JMeter?

Comment: what do you mean by `using loadrunner in JMeter`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

When you [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like:

```
jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/test.jmx -l /path/to/results.jtl
```

the [`results.jtl` file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) contains the "raw" data you're looking for.

Another option is adding a [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) like [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) and provide the filename and the metrics you want to store

[image]